# Hover effect on a menu letter

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, transform

This is my menus:

```
<TD vAlign="Middle" align="Center"><A href="/?open_the=gate"><SPAN class="H">H</SPAN>ome</A></TD>
<TD vAlign="Middle" align="Center"><A href="/?open_the=book"><SPAN class="B">B</SPAN>ook</A></TD>
<TD vAlign="Middle" align="Center"><A href="/?open_the=contact_page"><SPAN class="C">C</SPAN>ontact <SPAN class="P">P</SPAN>age</A></TD>
```

CSS:

```
.H:Hover
{
    DISPLAY: Inline-Block;
    TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    -O-TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    -MS-TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    -MOZ-TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    -KHTML-TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    -WEBKIT-TRANSFORM: RotateY(180deg);
    }
```

So I basically want to apply the TRANSFORM effect on the capital letters whenever I hover over the menus links. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work only when you hover specifically on the letters **H**, **B**, **C** and **P**

Use the hover of `a` to achieve the requested effect. Below is an working example.

```css
a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
a:hover span {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -khtml-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<td valign="middle" align="center">
  <a href="/?open_the=gate"><span>H</span>ome</a>
</td>
<td valign="middle" align="center">
  <a href="/?open_the=book"><span>B</span>ook</a>
</td>
<td valign="middle" align="center">
  <a href="/?open_the=contact_page"><span>C</span>ontact <span>P</span>age</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Marvellous. Thank you!